# if / else path not as expected on return value of last command

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
       sh $CPB_BIN/nm187_sort.sh $CPB_TRANS/$SORT_FILE_ORIGINAL $CPB_TRANS/$OUTPUT_FILE

       if [ $? == -1 ]
       then
          print "Nonmon sort command failed: $!\n"
                      exit 1
       else
          print "Nonmon sort command exited with value $?\n"
```

For some reason if the sort script fails, its still taking the else part. What am i missing?

Comment: Also, it's best to quote the the exit status variable in the statement, and only one = is necessary really.

Comment: `$?` cannot ever equal `-1`. Return codes are `[0-255]`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Face Palm! Hahaha

Comment: Note the last line posted will not have the value you expect in `$?` -- `$?` contains the exit status of the **previous command**, and there the previous command is `[` from the "if" conditional clause, and since you're in the else part, $? will be 1 always. After you run the `sh sort.sh ...` command, you need to capture the exit status with something like `rc=$?`, then `if (( $rc == 255 )); then ...; else echo exit status is $rc; fi`